# Resizing Excel Chart Using VBA in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I know this question has been asked before but as I am no VBA expert, I can't seem to get any of the solutions to work for my particular scenario so I was hoping someone could help.

I have some VBA code that copies a selection from Excel, opens a new powerpoint presentation based on a template and then pastes the data into slide two of powerpoint.

The only thing I want to do now is manipulate the size and position of the chart once it is there. What do I need to add to this code below to make that happen?

```
   'Opens a new PowerPoint presentation based on template and pastes data into Slide 2 of Powerpoint from Excel

Dim PPapp As PowerPoint.Application, PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation, PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim XLws As Worksheet

    Set XLws = ActiveSheet
    Set PPapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPpres = PPapp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Colin\Dropbox (Edge45)\Edge45 Team Folder\Edge45 Company Documents\Templates\Powerpoint Templates\Edge45 Audit Template Macro.potm", Untitled:=msoTrue)
    PPapp.Visible = True
    Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(2)
    XLws.Range("A1:D16").Copy
    PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a Shape object and play around :

```
'Opens a new PowerPoint presentation based on template and pastes data into Slide 2 of Powerpoint from Excel

Dim PPapp As PowerPoint.Application, PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation, PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide, PPShape As Object
Dim XLws As Worksheet

Set XLws = ActiveSheet
Set PPapp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set PPpres = PPapp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Colin\Dropbox (Edge45)\Edge45 Team Folder\Edge45 Company Documents\Templates\Powerpoint Templates\Edge45 Audit Template Macro.potm", Untitled:=msoTrue)
PPapp.Visible = True
Set PPslide = PPpres.Slides(2)
XLws.Range("A1:D16").Copy
Set PPShape = PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With PPShape
    .Top = 10
    .Height = 100
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 100
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I get a run time time error type 13 mis match whatever that is with your amended code  - Unfortunately I have no idea what that means - Any ideas?

Comment: @superhans : Try the edit, I don't know why but apparently PowerPoint changes the type when it's pasted!

Comment: @superhans : I changed the code in my answer to (I hope !) solve the issue!

Comment: If the sheet is long, can Powerpoint show it with a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @JaredThirsk : I'd say no... The only thing I found, might be (inside `With PPShape`): `.AutoShapeType = msoShapeVerticalScroll`
(If not recognized in Excel => `Const msoShapeVerticalScroll = 101 (&H65)`) Let me know how it goes !

Comment: @JaredThirsk : so ?

Comment: @R3uK I went with another approach, flipping between one half on each slide, and using a custom back button with a full history.